# how to exclude tags of certain types using LESS css

Tags: css, less

How can I write `"input:not([type="submit"])"` using LESS? I think the CSS syntax does not work with IE, is there a LESS command that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. LESS can't do more than pure CSS - it's just more convenient to write. As a workaround until *not:* is available you could use something like

```
input {
    /* set properties for all input types */
    &[type="submit] {
        /* undo for type submit */
    }
}
```